# Classes not accessing global objects

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

This is really puzzling me.  For some reason I get a

> "c1 not declared in this scope"

error from the compiler.  I am usig Mingw with Code::Blocks.  I would assume global variables are global to the program?  Am I wrong? TYIA -Roland

```
    // main.h
    #include <iostream>

    #include "classone.cpp"
    #include "classtwo.cpp"

    extern AnotherClass c2;
    extern TheClass c1;


----------

    // main.cpp
    #include "main.h"

    AnotherClass c2;
    TheClass c1;

    int main()
    {

        c1.function5();
        c2.function2();

        return 0;
    }


----------

    //classone.h

    #include "main.h"
    class AnotherClass  {
    `
          public:
        void function2();

    void function3();

      private:
    int varone;
    int vartwo;
};


----------

// classone.cpp

#include "classone.h"

void AnotherClass::function2()  {

    std::cout << "Function 2 Check\n";
}

void AnotherClass::function3()  {

    std::cout << "Function 3 Check";
}


----------

// classtwo.h

#include "main.h"
class TheClass  {

      public:
    void function4();
    void function5();
};


----------

// classtwo.cpp
#include "classtwo.h"

void TheClass::function4()  {

    c1.function2();
    std::cout << "Function 2 Check\n";
}

void TheClass::function5()  {

    std::cout << "Function 3 Check";
}
```

Comment: ThClass::Function4() is where the error is flagged

Comment: Stop defining global variables in header files. *Declare* their existence (via extern) in the proper header, then *define* that existence in a single .c/cpp file. Finally, include the declaring header wherever you need access to the global. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525496/declaring-initializing-and-using-a-global-variable-in-same-header-file) for a related case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite silly to include .cpp files like that - only include headers.

Anyway, change main.h to this:

```
#include <iostream>
extern AnotherClass c2;
extern TheClass c1;
```

Add this to main.cpp:

```
AnotherClass c2;
TheClass c1;
```

Then include `main.h` in each file which needs it, like this:

```
// classtwo.cpp
#include "classtwo.h"
#include "main.h"

void TheClass::function4()  {

    c1.function2();
    std::cout << "Function 2 Check\n";
}

void TheClass::function5()  {

    std::cout << "Function 3 Check";
}
```

Also, you need include guards if you don't have those already.

Comment: Thanks for the illuminating answer but I am still getting the same error

Comment: @RolandSams You need to move the main.cpp additions to global scope - outside of the main function.

Comment: Same error... This is a persistant one.  Updated source is there

Comment: @RolandSams stop including the .cpp files in main.h

Comment: undefined reference to `TheClass::function5()' ?

Comment: @RolandSams include the class headers in the main header. You should probably read a good C++ book.

Comment: Ok, anythimg further about this strange problem?  I think I can place an ugly hack using referances but I really don't want to

Comment: @RolandSams if there are any more problems then ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the class declarations in your .cpp files if you want to compile all the code in a single file. Inside classtwo.cpp insert #include "classtwo.h" and do the same for classone at the top of both files.

Standard practice is to separate the class code from the client code, so you should compile the classes into a library and link it to the main program.

Answer (score 0):

Your `main .h` needs to include the `.h` files of the 2 classes, for it to work. You do not (and should not ) need to include the `.cpp` files.