# Calling a method for a class attribute C++

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors

I am creating a custom class `pi2cma`  with an object `sigma` from another class as an atribute. However, when I try to directly call a method of `sigma` directly in the cpp file of `pi2cma` with `sigma.setMean(MN);`, I get the error:

`./src/pi2cma.cpp:54:7: error: ‘((pi2cma*)this)->pi2cma::sigma’ does not have class type`

If I however, create an intermediate method for class `pi2cma` that does exactly the same

`void pi2cma::set_MN(Eigen::VectorXd _mean){sigma.setMean(_mean);}`

No errors are reported!

How do I use the methods of the parent class of `sigma` directly in my `pi2cma.cpp`?

EDIT: Includes in `pi2cma.cpp`

```
#include "eigen_multivariate_normal.hpp"
#include "pi2cma.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

//aditional libraries for multivariate matrix manipulation
#include <boost/tr1/random.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
(...)
```

and in `pi2cma.hpp:`

```
(...)
// mean and covariance matrices
Eigen::VectorXd MN;
Eigen::MatrixXd CVM;

// multivariate normal distribution
Eigen::EigenMultivariateNormal<double,DIM> sigma(Eigen::VectorXd,Eigen::MatrixXd);
(...)
```

the `EigenMultivariteNormal` class in `eigen_multivariate_normal.hpp`:

```
template<typename Scalar, int Size>
class EigenMultivariateNormal
{
    Matrix<Scalar,Size,Size> _covar;
    Matrix<Scalar,Size,Size> _transform;
    Matrix< Scalar, Size, 1> _mean;
    internal::scalar_normal_dist_op<Scalar> randN; // Gaussian functor

public:
    EigenMultivariateNormal(const Matrix<Scalar,Size,1>& mean,const Matrix<Scalar,Size,Size>& covar)
    {
    setMean(mean);
    setCovar(covar);
    }

    void setMean(const Matrix<Scalar,Size,1>& mean) { _mean = mean; }
    void setCovar(const Matrix<Scalar,Size,Size>& covar) {
        _covar = covar;  
        SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Matrix<Scalar,Size,Size> > eigenSolver(_covar);
        _transform = eigenSolver.eigenvectors()*eigenSolver.eigenvalues().cwiseMax(0).cwiseSqrt().asDiagonal();

    }

    Matrix<Scalar,Size,-1> samples(int nn)
    {
    return (_transform * Matrix<Scalar,Size,-1>::NullaryExpr(Size,nn,randN)).colwise() + _mean;
    }
};
```

which I am calling in `pi2cma.cpp`:

```
void pi2cma::init(long init_exp){
(...)
sigma.setMean(MN); // error
set_MN(MN);        // works
    (...)
}
```

Comment: My crystal ball says the error is on line 42.

Comment: Mine says line 1 of pi2cma.cpp is missing #include "sigma.h"

Comment: Show the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `sigma` is a function:

```
Eigen::EigenMultivariateNormal<double,DIM> sigma(Eigen::VectorXd,Eigen::MatrixXd);
```

You cannot call member functions on a function.

Comment: I can guaratee it is not a function. It a class that implements a Multivariate Normal Distribution.

Comment: @joaocandre it is a function declaration in the code you have posted.

Comment: Then it is not properly declared in `pi2cma.hpp`. How do I declare it to be just an object of the class `EigenMultivariateNormal` without using the class constructor?

Comment: @joaocandre have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525496/declaring-initializing-and-using-a-global-variable-in-same-header-file).

Comment: Thing is, sigma is not supposed to be a global variable, but an atribute of the class `EigenMultivariateNormal`. Somehow I managed to avoid compiler errors by creating an empty constructor for the class, and then can simply declare `Eigen::EigenMultivariateNormal<double,DIM> sigma;` inside my `pi2cma` class. But I'm not sure if it is the best way, it does seem more like a workaround solution to a problem I still do not fully understand;

Answer (score 0):

in pi2cma.cpp

```
#include "sigma.h"
```

Comment: `sigma` is not the class, is an object of the class EigenMultivariateNormal from `eigen_multivariate_normal.hpp` file, which I am including in the `pi2cma.cpp` file